# Is it possible to do something similar to a type switch using reflection?

Tags: reflection, go

I need to do different things based on the type of the value being reflected.

```
value := reflect.ValueOf(someInterface)
```

I'd like to do something that has the following effect:

```
if <type of value> == <type1> {
    do something
} else if <type of value> == <type2> {
    do something
}
```

This is something similar to what a type switch does in go code.

Comment: Just to double check: the `type1` and `type2` are dynamic, correct? Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, they are types defined in go code.

Comment: Are you not able to use a type switch then?

Comment: How would I use type switch on the type Value (which reflection gives me)?

Comment: From your question, I don't know why `reflect.Value` is needed, but if that's all you have, you can do: `switch value.Interface().(type) { ...`

Comment: That makes sense. But made me realize I asked the wrong question. I am iterating over fields of a struct, and want to do different things based on the type of each field. Any ideas? Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are iterating over fields of a struct, you can use a type switch to perform different actions based off of the field's type:

```
value := reflect.ValueOf(s)
for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ {
    field := value.Field(i)
    if !field.CanInterface() {
        continue
    }
    switch v := field.Interface().(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Int: %d\n", v)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("String: %s\n", v)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-B3PWMqWTo

Comment: This will work - but not if the fields are nil. Is there a way to go by the types of the fields directly?

Comment: @Ziffusion: The type switch works on the field type, not the value. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/U82wLxOS98

Comment: @Ziffusion: The type switch works on the field type, not the value. See: https://play.golang.org/p/U82wLxOS98

Comment: What I mean is that what you have works off the type of the value of the fields. And it does work. But it won't work if the field values are nil. You can try it by changing your example code to NOT initialize the struct (leave the fields nil).

Comment: hmm .. that does work ... dunno what I am screwing up in my code

Comment: Any idea why this does not work? And how to make it work for this case?
https://play.golang.org/p/Pl4t-s4wEI

Comment: @Ziffusion: In order for `Interface()` to work, the field needs to be exported (i.e. its name needs to start with an uppercase letter): https://play.golang.org/p/v27UG0R7Nc